# best practices for backup and recover sharepoint 2007 sites

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am backing up a site collection  and restoring it to a new  farm

1)   Backup up the site collection

```
stsadm -o backup -url http://portal1/sites/currentsitecollection -filename site.bak
```

2) Create  a new site collection in the new farm

```
stsadm -o createsiteinnewdb   -url http://portal2/sites/restoredsitecollection -owneremail test'test.com -ownerlogin domain\admin -ownername admin -title site -description  Site description
-hostheaderwebapplicationurl http://portal2 -databaseuser admin -databasepassword password   -databaseserver  DB2 -databasename MyData
```

3) Restore the sitecollection

```
    stsadm -o restore -url http://portal2/sites/restoredsitecollection  -filename site.bak   -overwrite
```

What is the best practice to achieve it....

Answer (score 0):

The steps you mentioned are correct , but need to makesure you lock the site before backup and restore the site.You can follow the steps mentioned in this link.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc706871(v=office.12).aspx